# InvalidOperationException due to using more than one datamodel in the query

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, telerik-open-access

I am using Telerik open Access. I have three data models and for the three data models I have three different Context Modules.

In my query I want to retrieve the data using joining of different tables in different data models. I wrote the query but it is throwing this error:

> InvalidOperationException Unhandled By user code.

How can I retrieve the data if we have different datamodels in the project?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the data separately and join it in memory, however it is impossible to query data in different models directly.